# Is it okay to use many anonymous functions?

Tags: go, coding-style

One thing I love from golang is `defer` statement, but `defer` only work on `func` scope.

So, I very often to use it like this

```
func (s *Something) abc() error {
    func() {
        s.Lock()
        defer s.Unlock()
        // don't lock too long
    }()
    // do something else
    if err := func() error {
        resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com/api")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
            return errors.New("Failed to download")
        }
        var tmp struct {
            Error bool    `json:"error"`
            Result string `json:"result"`
        }
        if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&tmp); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if tmp.Error {
            return errors.New("API return error")
        }
        s.somedata = tmp.result
        return nil
    }(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    func() {
        s.Lock()
        defer s.Unlock()
        // don't lock too long
    }()
    // do something else
}
```

basically, I wrap it into anonymous block `func`.

Is it common to use something like this? do any other gophers abuse this fact?

EDIT: Clarification

Okay, it looks like I didn't explain it well,
There are 2 things I want to achieve

1. What I want to achieve is to lock mutex as short as possible

   ```
   func() {
       s.Lock()
       defer s.Unlock()
       // don't lock too long

       // there is other code here, this func is not an empty func
   }()
   ```
2. There more than one http.Get in this function, let's say after calling example.com/api I need to call example.com/api2 . We need to close resp.Body as soon as possible, so only one TCP connection is made to this server. AFAIK, http.Get will create another TCP connection if there is another HTTP connection that not closed yet (resp.Body.Close() is not called on previous response).

EDIT 2: more clarification

first and last anonymous function and lock are to sync cache. I implement cache based on map[string]string, so it needs to be sync-ed.

I need to call example.com/api first, and based on the response I need to call example.com/api2 or example.com/api3, and at that time previous http connection must be closed, it can be code like this

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com/api")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
    resp.Body.Close()
    return errors.New("Failed to download")
}
// process the body
resp.Body.Close()
```

but you need to explicitly write resp.Body.Close() twice

Comment: The readability of your code is awful.  I don't think your use of anonymous functions is very clear nor tidy here, but it really is opinion based, so I'm voting to close.  Additionally, what do you *think* happens when you lock on `s` in your first anonymous functional?  Are you sure you understand how `defer` works?

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do here even if you had written the code without the func() (which has only s.Lock and a deferred s.Unlock) it would have worked the same way, see https://play.golang.org/p/U18AkCwrAOB

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. At first it's don't explain why I do this

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark, sorry my bad, that first and third anonymous function is not an empty function. What i want to achieve is to lock as short as possible, because defer only completed when the func return

Comment: @Ravi, sorry my bad, that function is not empty function, I forgot to say that in question

Comment: You understand that s does not have a lock on it at the `// do something else` line, right?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark, yes, I know that. Actually, that is what I want.

Comment: How does it make a difference if all the code inside your function were outside (minus the defer) - it'll work the same way. Also you should probably look at making the http calls in different go routines and then stream the results back using a channel, waiting for all the results to be accumulated. You can use the same http.Client (see https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

Comment: thanks @Ravi, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597261/golang-it-is-okay-to-use-many-anonymous-function?noredirect=1#comment88205364_50597501

Comment: Continuing on what I mentioned earlier, it may be safer to use `http.Client` than calling `http.Get`, see https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779 As such this has nothing to do with what you originally asked, but it's something one would better know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in the observation that `defer` only works in function scope, I think that the problem you are running into is nothing to do with the behaviour of `defer`.

In general it's [insert opinion] better to have smaller functions, then you would not need to create anonymous functions to maximise the usage of `defer`.

Splitting up your example, something like this might be better:

```
// Public method that does locking orchestration
func (s *Something) PublicDoABC() error {
    s.doWorkStart()
    if err := s.populateSomeData(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.doWorkEnd()
    return nil
}

// setup function with locking
func (s *Something) doWorkStart() {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()

    // do setup work here
}

// teardown function with locking
func (s *Something) doWorkEnd() {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()

    // do teardown work here
}

// do the actual request
func (s *Something) populateSomeData() error {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com/api")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        return errors.New("Failed to download")
    }
    var tmp struct {
        Error bool    `json:"error"`
        Result string `json:"result"`
    }
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if tmp.Error {
        return errors.New("API return error")
    }
    s.somedata = tmp.Result
    return nil
}
```

I know this changes things, and you might not want to split out the body of the function, you could define a method on `Something` that allows arbitrary functions to be executed with locking:

```
func (s *Something) PublicDoABC() error {
    s.executeLocked(func() {
        // do setup work
    })
    if err := s.populateSomeData(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    s.executeLocked(func() {
        // do teardown work
    })

    return nil
}

// this function allows defer unlocks and unifies locking code
func (s *Something) executeLocked(f func()) {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()
    f()
}
```

**To answer the original question**: No, I do not believe this is that common (having multiple inline anon function). If it feels wrong, there's almost certainly a better way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, the last paragraph is what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your anonymous functions to `Lock` and `Unlock` you'll enter the anonymous function, lock, defer an unlock, leave the anonymous function triggering the deferred unlock, and then continue `abc()`. The beginning and ending anonymous functions are pretty much useless.

Your middle anonymous function is bad style for any language. There's no reason to just not do the code and respond to any returned errors.

I would rewrite this function as follows:

```
func (s *Something) abc() error {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()

    resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com/api")
    if err != nil {
            return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
            return errors.New("Failed to download")
    }
    // This struct should probably be global
    var tmp struct {
            Error bool    `json:"error"`
            Result string `json:"result"`
    }
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&tmp)
    if err != nil {
            return err
    }
    if tmp.Error {
            return errors.New("API return error")
    }
    s.somedata = tmp.result
    return nil
}
```

Anonymous functions have their place. I've used them for closures as well as extremely concise go routines. One place you might use an anonymous function here is to log an error returned by `resp.Body.Close()` like so:

```
defer func() {
    err = resp.Body.Close()
    log.Printf("error closing API response body: %s", err)
}()
```

Comment: I've edited my question. So what about if I want to do another HTTP GET, that second HTTP GET will create TCP connection because old one is not considered complete yet (body is not closed yet)

Comment: Sounds like a code structure problem that anonymous functions would only muddle up. Each request could/should be in their own named function and you can do a defer and have only one connection. If you really want you could just Close the request without doing a defer, but where's the fun in that?

Comment: The short answer is for years I've used very few anonymous functions in Go. In your situations you abstractly do ThingA in an anonymous function, you do a web request, then you do some other ThingB. I'd make those 3 different functions and think through their accessibility.

Comment: thanks @corey-ogburn , that is what I think first, decompose it into multiple functions, but sometimes I stumbled with naming that function, haha